# When does the DataBinding event fire during the ASP .NET page lifecycle?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, events

Simply, if I have a GridView with a SqlDataSource control declarative set as its data source, when does that data source retrieve its data and when does the binding take place in the page lifecycle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the 'preRender' phase - look at the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20190914035159/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

This article about [Page Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is pretty good.

> For example, suppose you have a GridView that displays a company record in each row along with a list of the company officers in a ListBox control. To fill the list of officers, you would bind the ListBox control to a data source control (such as SqlDataSource) that retrieves the company officer data using the CompanyID in a query.
>
> If the ListBox control's data-binding
>   properties, such as DataSourceID and
>   DataMember, are set declaratively, the
>   ListBox control will try to bind to
>   its data source during the containing
>   row's DataBinding event. However, the
>   CompanyID field of the row does not
>   contain a value until the GridView
>   control's RowDataBound event occurs.
>   In this case, the child control (the
>   ListBox control) is bound before the
>   containing control (the GridView
>   control) is bound, so their
>   data-binding stages are out of sync.
>
> To avoid this condition, put the data
>   source control for the ListBox control
>   in the same template item as the
>   ListBox control itself, and do not set
>   the data binding properties of the
>   ListBox declaratively. Instead, set
>   them programmatically at run time
>   during the RowDataBound event, so that
>   the ListBox control does not bind to
>   its data until the CompanyID
>   information is available.